# Error occurred while convert the dataTable to excel.

Tags: excel, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I got these error message while click the export button in the sever. I can't convert that table.

I used primeface 5.0 and netbeans 8.0.2 version and GlassFish server 4.1

How can i solve this problem?

This is my home.xhtml file.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable value="#{linkController.links}" var="lis" rowKey="#{lis.link_id}" selectionMode="single" id="tbl">

                <p:column headerText="Id">
                    <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
                    #{lis.link_id}
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="name">
                    #{lis.link_name}
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="date">
                    #{lis.date}
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="time">
                    #{lis.time}
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="uplink">
                    #{lis.upLink}
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="downlink">
                    #{lis.downLink}
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

            <p:commandButton value="Save as excel"> 
                <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tbl" fileName="kananee" pageOnly="true" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>  



    </h:body>


</html>
```

Comment: This is the error ..
SEVERE:   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString
 at org.primefaces.component.export.ExporterFactory.getExporterForType(ExporterFactory.java:30)
 at org.primefaces.component.export.DataExporter.processAction(DataExporter.java:88)

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory, and confirmed in the Primefaces manual:

> For pdf exporting **itext** and for xls exporting **poi** libraries are
>   required in the classpath.

So here you go: https://poi.apache.org/download.html

Comment: I downloaded "poi-bin-3.12-20150511.tar" how to add to the classpath. @Zim

Comment: It depends on your project configuration. Do you use Eclipse? Maven?